# Determining if values of previous rows repeat in dataframe

Tags: r

I have some data organized like this:

```
set.seed(12)

ids <- matrix(replicate(1000,sample(LETTERS[1:4],2)),ncol=2,byrow=T)

df <- data.frame(
  event = 1:100,
  id1 = ids[,1],
  id2 = ids[,2],
  grp = rep(1:10, each=100), stringsAsFactors=F)

head(df,10)

   event id1 id2 grp
1      1   A   C   1
2      2   D   A   1
3      3   A   D   1
4      4   A   B   1
5      5   A   D   1
6      6   B   C   1
7      7   B   D   1
8      8   B   D   1
9      9   B   D   1
10    10   C   A   1
```

There are pairs of ids (id1 & id2). Within a row they are never the same.  There is a variable called grp. There are 10 groups. Each group could be considered a separate sample of data.  The event variable goes from 1-100 in each group.

The first question I have is quite straightforward. Within each group, for each row, is the combination of the two ids (id1-id2) the same as the previous row, the reverse of the previous row, or neither of these two options.  Obviously, if there is an A-C combination on row 100 of one group, I am not interested in whether it is reversed, the same or whatever on row 1 of the following group.

This is my temporary solution:

```
#Give each id pair and identifier:
df$pair <- paste(pmin(df$id1,df$id2), pmax(df$id1,df$id2))

#For each grp, work out using `lag` if previous row contains same pair of ids, and if they are in same or reversed order:

df.sp <- split(df, df$grp)
df$value <- unlist(lapply(df.sp, function(x) ifelse(x$pair!=lag(x$pair), NA, ifelse(x$id1==lag(x$id1), 1, 0)) ))
```

This gives:

```
head(df,10)
   event id1 id2 grp pair value
1      1   A   C   1  A C    NA
2      2   D   A   1  A D    NA
3      3   A   D   1  A D     0
4      4   A   B   1  A B    NA
5      5   A   D   1  A D    NA
6      6   B   C   1  B C    NA
7      7   B   D   1  B D    NA
8      8   B   D   1  B D     1
9      9   B   D   1  B D     1
10    10   C   A   1  A C    NA
```

This works - showing 0 as a reversal, 1 as a copy and NA as neither.

The more complex question I am interested in is the following.   Within each group (grp), for each row, find if its combination of two ids (the pair) previously occurred in that grp.  If they did, then return whether they were in the same order or reversed order the immediate previous time they occurred.

That result would look like this:

```
   event id1 id2 grp pair value
1      1   A   C   1  A C    NA
2      2   D   A   1  A D    NA
3      3   A   D   1  A D     0
4      4   A   B   1  A B    NA
5      5   A   D   1  A D     1
6      6   B   C   1  B C    NA
7      7   B   D   1  B D    NA
8      8   B   D   1  B D     1
9      9   B   D   1  B D     1
10    10   C   A   1  A C     0
```

e.g. row 10 is returned as a 0 because the combination A-C previously occurred and was in the reverse order (row 1).  on row 5 a 1 is returned as A-D previously occurred in the same order on row 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there! The second question is equivalent to the first question, just grouping by `pair` as well as `group`. I converted the code to `dplyr` (though I appreciate the spirit behind keeping the question in `base`). I also removed the second `ifelse`, replacing it with a numeric conversion of the logical, which should be more performant (and some will find easier to read).

```
df %>% group_by(grp) %>%
    mutate(
        pair = paste(pmin(id1, id2), pmax(id1, id2)),
        prev_row = ifelse(pair != lag(pair), NA, as.numeric(id1 == lag(id1)))
    ) %>%
    group_by(grp, pair) %>%
    mutate(prev_any = ifelse(pair != lag(pair), NA, as.numeric(id1 == lag(id1)))) %>%
    head(10)
# Source: local data frame [10 x 7]
# Groups: grp, pair [5]
#
#    event   id1   id2   grp  pair prev_row prev_any
#    (int) (chr) (chr) (int) (chr)    (dbl)    (dbl)
# 1      1     A     C     1   A C       NA       NA
# 2      2     D     A     1   A D       NA       NA
# 3      3     A     D     1   A D        0        0
# 4      4     A     B     1   A B       NA       NA
# 5      5     A     D     1   A D       NA        1
# 6      6     B     C     1   B C       NA       NA
# 7      7     B     D     1   B D       NA       NA
# 8      8     B     D     1   B D        1        1
# 9      9     B     D     1   B D        1        1
# 10    10     C     A     1   A C       NA        0
```

Answer (score 2):

For such grouping, filtering and mutating tasks, I find dplyr to be very helpful. Here is one way I came up with how you can achieve your goal:

```
df %>% group_by(grp) %>% mutate(value = ifelse(id1 == lag(id1) & id2 == lag(id2), 1, ifelse(id1 == lag(id2) & id2 == lag(id1), 0, NA)))
```

Within each group, you compare the ID values and conditionally assign a new value column. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks. Yes, I actually did this with `dplyr` and `purrr` but didn't use it in the question (some people don't like the `%>%` - I don't know why, I think it's great).  However, I'm looking for a more generalized solution to the question at the bottom of the post.